# How is defined current url in zend (inside job of a framework)

Tags: zend-framework, php

Tell please what script uses zend framework for definition current URL? More exactly I interest what use ZEND for definition domain name: this  `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or this 
 `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ? (or may be something other)?

P.S. ( I search in documentation but not found, (I do not know this framework), also I search in google, but also not found answer on my question? )

Comment: ZF 1 or 2? & `$request->getRequestUri()` doesn't contains the domain, so this would be two separate question.

Comment: As I understood ZF2 will be more new (and better) version :) so anwer: `ZF2`.

"$request->getRequestUri() doesn't contains the domain" 

its how? url must be contain domain also always, right?

Comment: no, `getRequestUri()` reflects to what comes from the HTTP protocol's first row (f.ex. `HTTP/1.1 GET /path/to/file`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use: `$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()`  to get current of requested URI.

In the view script use: `$this->url()` to get current URL.

Or using via static integrated Zend Controller front via instance:

`$uri = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();`

You can get a value of URI implementation via singleton to get a value of request() data:

```
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$url = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost();
```

On the View use it as:

```
echo $this->serverUrl(true); # return with controller, action,...
```

You should avoid hardcode such as example (NOT TO USE!):

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

instead of this example use as on a view:

```
$uri = $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost() . $this->view->url();
```

If you want using getRequest in ZEND more explore [The Request Object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html).

**SKIP IT BELOW (AUTOPSY EXAMPLE HOW WORKS IT).**

Full of example code how getRequestUri() how it works and why is isRequest instead using `$_SERVER` is because on a platform specific is randomly get a data:

first if uri null, thand if requested from IIS set is as HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL. If not, check on IIS7 rewritten uri (include encoded uri). If not on IIS than REQUEST_URI will check scheme of HTTP_HOSTNAME, or if failed use as ORIG_PATH_INFO and grab a QUERY_STRING.

If is setted, grab a data automatically via string of returned object `$this` in a class.

If failed, than will be set a parsed string than set it.

```
if ($requestUri === null) {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'])) { // check this first so IIS will catch
            $requestUri = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
        } elseif (
            // IIS7 with URL Rewrite: make sure we get the unencoded url (double slash problem)
            isset($_SERVER['IIS_WasUrlRewritten'])
            && $_SERVER['IIS_WasUrlRewritten'] == '1'
            && isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'])
            && $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'] != ''
            ) {
            $requestUri = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            // Http proxy reqs setup request uri with scheme and host [and port] + the url path, only use url path
            $schemeAndHttpHost = $this->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getHttpHost();
            if (strpos($requestUri, $schemeAndHttpHost) === 0) {
                $requestUri = substr($requestUri, strlen($schemeAndHttpHost));
            }
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'])) { // IIS 5.0, PHP as CGI
            $requestUri = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
            if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
                $requestUri .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            }
        } else {
            return $this;
        }
    } elseif (!is_string($requestUri)) {
        return $this;
    } else {
        // Set GET items, if available
        if (false !== ($pos = strpos($requestUri, '?'))) {
            // Get key => value pairs and set $_GET
            $query = substr($requestUri, $pos + 1);
            parse_str($query, $vars);
            $this->setQuery($vars);
        }
    }

    $this->_requestUri = $requestUri;
    return $this;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is great answer for this framework users, but I interest something else... that is, I interest how is defined cuurent url into this metod: `getRequestUri()`, what script are writed into this method for define current url (more exactly domain name)?

this `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` ? excuse me for my english.

Comment: Look at here http://www.sourcecodebrowser.com/zend-framework/1.10.3/_request_2_http_test_case_8php_source.html and click on `return $this->_requestUri;` You can view how it works.